# Crankset compatibility: Can I replace Shimano FC-M521 with FC-T4010?

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket, chainring, drivetrain

I recently bought a Jamis Coda Elite (2012) second hand. I'm slowly replacing all of the drive train as most of the components are worn.

According to p114 of [the original product catalogue](https://www.jamisbikes.com/catalog_archive/12_JAMIS_CATALOG.pdf), the bike ships with a Shimano FC-M521 triple 48/36/26T crankset with 175mm arms. I'm new to bike maintenance and have tried to do some research, and it looks like the [Shimano Alivio FC-T4010](https://www.bikester.co.uk/shimano-alivio-fc-t4010-crank-set-octalink-9-speed-M129675.html?vgid=G383939&_cid=21_1_-1_9_34_383939__pla&ef_id=CjwKCAjwuYWSBhByEiwAKd_n_r96u6C-cOifEnLIh-pCMpBxxQh-tJkd6D_VqF1b8iS4JtwfLUeA4RoCuRwQAvD_BwE:G:s&campaign_detail=smart_shopping&gclid=CjwKCAjwuYWSBhByEiwAKd_n_r96u6C-cOifEnLIh-pCMpBxxQh-tJkd6D_VqF1b8iS4JtwfLUeA4RoCuRwQAvD_BwE) would be a compatible replacement.

Would somebody be able to confirm this for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both have the same 50 mm chain line, both are Octalink, but M521 requires 121 mm long BB spindle and T4010 126 mm spindle. That means you should also replace the bottom bracket. If that is required, you can as well look at other cranksets, e.g. those that use the Hollowtech II bottom brackets.

M521 is nominally 10-speed, but I understand that the rest of your drivetrain is 9-speed.

Comment: The catalogue gives the measure 68/113 for the BB — is that second measurement the spindle length? Does it make a difference moving to a BB with a longer spindle?

Comment: Yes, I have a 9-speed cassette and chain. Is it worth upgrading to Hollowtech? Are you able to suggest any cranksets? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @jbowman 113 is the spindle lenght, the shortest one.  T4010 requires a longer one. Upgrading to Hollowtech II does make sense if a good crankset you can buy requires it. Availability of parts is also important these days.

Comment: Also, make double sure that your crankset is actually those 175 mm. Check your bike not just the catalogue, the catalogue lists more options that depend on the size of your bike. I now fou.d out that different versions of M521 require BB spindles of different lengths.